# Multiple different conditions and if statments within a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I want to assign different letters from `A:U` to a new column vector according to some conditions that depend on a different column that takes the numbers `1:99`.

I came up with the following solution, but I want to write it more efficiently.

```
for (i in 1:99){

  if (i %in% 1:3 == T  ){
    id<-which(H07_NACE$NACE2.Code==i)
    H07_NACE$NACE2.Sectors[id]<-"A"
  }


   .............         

    if (i %in% 45:60 == T  ){
      id<-which(H07_NACE$NACE2.Code==i)
      H07_NACE$NACE2.Sectors[id]<-"D"
    }
      .....................


     if (i == 99  ){
id<-which(H07_NACE$NACE2.Code==i)
H07_NACE$NACE2.Sectors[id]<-"U"
  }

}
```

In the previous code I skipped multiple other line which essentially do the same thing. Notice that conditions changing all the time within this loop that I created and are of two *types*. One is for example of the type `i %in% 45:60 == T` and the other of the type 'i == 99 '

My original code has multiple such **ifs** within this loop so any help on how I can write it more efficiently or compactly will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us some data to work with and expected output?

Comment: I would use `if else`s instead of plain `if`s, since your conditions seem independent, so that once it finds the right bracket it doesn't check the rest. In your current code it evaluates all conditions.

Comment: You can use a vector with your constraints and a little indexing should quickly get you what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user has requested to map the numbers given in `H07_NACE$NACE2.Code` to the letters `"A"` to `"U"` according to given rules he has hardcoded in a number of `if` clauses.

A more flexible approach (and less tedious to code) is to use a *lookup table* (or *constraint vector* as Joseph Wood called it [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47718805/3817004)).

With `data.table`, we can use either a *rolling join* or a *non-equi update join* to do the mapping.

#### Sample data to be mapped

```
set.seed(1)
H07_NACE <- data.frame(NACE2.Code = sample(99, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

#### Rolling join

For the rolling join, we specify the mapping rules by tiling the number range `1:99` contiguously and giving the start number of each tile.

```
library(data.table)
# set up lookup table
lookup <- data.table(Code = c(1, 4, 21, 45, 61:75, 98, 99),
                     Sector = LETTERS[1:21])
lookup
```

> ```
>     Code Sector
>  1:    1      A
>  2:    4      B
>  3:   21      C
>  4:   45      D
>  5:   61      E
>  6:   62      F
>  7:   63      G
>  8:   64      H
>  9:   65      I
> 10:   66      J
> 11:   67      K
> 12:   68      L
> 13:   69      M
> 14:   70      N
> 15:   71      O
> 16:   72      P
> 17:   73      Q
> 18:   74      R
> 19:   75      S
> 20:   98      T
> 21:   99      U
>     Code Sector
> ```

```
# map Code to Sector 
lookup[setDT(H07_NACE), on = .(Code = NACE2.Code), roll = TRUE]
```

> ```
>     Code Sector
>  1:   27      C
>  2:   37      C
>  3:   57      D
>  4:   90      S
>  5:   20      B
>  6:   89      S
>  7:   94      S
>  8:   66      J
>  9:   63      G
> 10:    7      B
> ```

If the `H07_NACE` is to be updated we can append a new column by

```
setDT(H07_NACE)[, NACE2.Sector := lookup[H07_NACE, on = .(Code = NACE2.Code), 
  roll = TRUE, Sector]][]
```

> ```
>     NACE2.Code NACE2.Sector
>  1:         27            C
>  2:         37            C
>  3:         57            D
>  4:         90            S
>  5:         20            B
>  6:         89            S
>  7:         94            S
>  8:         66            J
>  9:         63            G
> 10:          7            B
> ```

#### Non-equi update join

For the non-equi update join, we specify the mapping rules by giving the lower and upper bounds. This can be derived from `lookup` by

```
lookup2 <- lookup[, .(Sector, lower = Code, 
                      upper = shift(Code - 1L, type = "lead", fill = max(Code)))]
lookup2
```

> ```
>     Sector lower upper
>  1:      A     1     3
>  2:      B     4    20
>  3:      C    21    44
>  4:      D    45    60
>  5:      E    61    61
>  6:      F    62    62
>  7:      G    63    63
>  8:      H    64    64
>  9:      I    65    65
> 10:      J    66    66
> 11:      K    67    67
> 12:      L    68    68
> 13:      M    69    69
> 14:      N    70    70
> 15:      O    71    71
> 16:      P    72    72
> 17:      Q    73    73
> 18:      R    74    74
> 19:      S    75    97
> 20:      T    98    98
> 21:      U    99    99
>     Sector lower upper
> ```

The new column is created by

```
setDT(H07_NACE)[lookup2, on = .(NACE2.Code >= lower, NACE2.Code <= upper), 
                NACE2.Sector := Sector][]
```

> ```
>     NACE2.Code NACE2.Sector
>  1:         27            C
>  2:         37            C
>  3:         57            D
>  4:         90            S
>  5:         20            B
>  6:         89            S
>  7:         94            S
>  8:         66            J
>  9:         63            G
> 10:          7            B
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick and dirty solution that should do the job (I'm sure there is more efficient/elegant way to do this). We can setup a constraint vector and use indexing from there to produce the desired results.

```
## Here is some random data that resembles the OP's
set.seed(3)
H07_NACE <- data.frame(NACE2.Code = sample(99, replace = TRUE))

## "T" is the 20th element... we need to gurantee
## that the number corresponding to "U" 
## corresponds to max(NACE2.Code)
maxCode <- max(H07_NACE$NACE2.Code)
constraintVec <- sort(sample(maxCode - 1, 20))
constraintVec <- c(constraintVec, maxCode)

H07_NACE$NACE2.Sector <- LETTERS[vapply(H07_NACE$NACE2.Code, function(x) {
                                            which(constraintVec >= x)[1]
                                    }, 1L)]

## Add optional check column to ensure we are mapping the 
## Code to the correct Sector
H07_NACE$NACE2.Check <- constraintVec[vapply(H07_NACE$NACE2.Code, function(x) {
    which(constraintVec >= x)[1]
}, 1L)]

head(H07_NACE)
  NACE2.Code NACE2.Sector NACE2.Check
1         17            E          18
2         80            R          85
3         39            K          54
4         33            J          37
5         60            N          66
6         60            N          66
```

## Update courtesy of @Frank

As suspected, there is a much simpler solution assuming the above logic is correct.  We use `findInterval` and set the arguments `rightmost.closed` and `left.open` to `TRUE` (we also have to add `1L` to the resulting vector):

```
H07_NACE$NACE2.Sector2 <- LETTERS[findInterval(H07_NACE$NACE2.Code, constraintVec,
                                    rightmost.closed = TRUE, , left.open = TRUE) + 1L]

head(H07_NACE)
  NACE2.Code NACE2.Sector NACE2.Check NACE2.Sector2
1         17            E          18             E
2         80            R          85             R
3         39            K          54             K
4         33            J          37             J
5         60            N          66             N
6         60            N          66             N

identical(H07_NACE$NACE2.Sector, H07_NACE$NACE2.Sector2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Maybe something like `findInterval(Code, Constraint)` could be used to simplify. Unclear since the OP used pseudocode...

Comment: I did not post any dataframe because I thought will be easy and straight forward to produce one. I was mostly concerned to find another way to do the exact same thing as my pseudocode shows. I will update soon.

Answer (score 1):

Here's two `tidyverse` examples, though I'm not completely certain what the original poster is really asking for.

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(NACE2.Code = sample(99, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(Sectors = ifelse(NACE2.Code %in% 1:3, "A", 
                          ifelse(NACE2.Code %in% 45:60, "D",
                                 ifelse(NACE2.Code ==99, "U", NA))))

data.frame(NACE2.Code = sample(99, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(Sectors = case_when(NACE2.Code %in% 1:3 ~ "A", 
                             NACE2.Code %in% 45:60 ~ "D",
                             NACE2.Code ==99 ~ "U")) %>% 
  drop_na
```